# Coherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^1$. How to show that there exists a unique exact sequence of the form

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)^{\oplus a}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^{\oplus b}\to F\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)^{\oplus c}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^{\oplus d}\to 0?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be some more elegant arguments, but here is one.

The hypercohomology of such complex should be zero. Since $\mathcal O(-1)$ have no cohomology, the usual spectral sequence implies that $\mathcal O^{\oplus b}=H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal O$ and $\mathcal O^{\oplus d}=H^1(F)\otimes \mathcal O$. Moreover, the map 
$$
H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal O\to F
$$
has to be the natural map. This should pretty much give uniqueness.

For the existence, let's do this. Consider the map $H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal O\to F$ and its image $G$. We have an inclusion $0\to G\to F$, which means that there is an inclusion $H^0(G)\to H^0(F)$. Since the composition 
$$H^0(F)=H^0(H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal O))\to H^0(G)\to H^0(F)$$
is identity, we see that $H^0(G)=H^0(F)$.

Now consider the short exact sequence
$$0\to G_1\to H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal O\to G\to 0$$
where $G_1$ is the kernel. We would like to show that $G_1$ is a direct sum of some number of copies of $\mathcal O(-1)$. From the long exact sequence in cohomology we conclude that $H^0(G_1)=H^1(G_1)=0$. Since it is a sub sheaf of a locally free sheaf, it is itself locally free (we are on a curve). Moreover, on $\mathbb P^1$, it has to be a direct sum of $\mathcal O(-r_i)$, so easily all $r_i$ are equal to $1$.
While we are at it, observe that the long exact sequence in cohomology shows that $H^1(G)=0$.

So we have established the first half of the sequence
$$
0\to G_1=\mathcal O(-1)^{\oplus a}\to \mathcal O^{\oplus b}\to F.
$$

Now we have 
$$
0\to G\to F\to G_2\to 0.
$$
We know that $H^0(G)\to H^0(F)$ is an isomorphism and $H^1(G)=0$. This implies that $H^0(G_2)=0$ and $H^1(F)\to H^1(G_2)$ is an isomorphism.

Since $H^0(G_2)=0$, $G_2$ is torsion-free and is a direct sum of $\mathcal O(-r_i)$ for some $r_i>0$. So it becomes a question of showing that there is a way of writing every such bundle as a kernel of a map from some number of copies of $\mathcal O(-1)$ to some number of copies of $\mathcal O$. By dualizing, it becomes a question of writing 
$$
0\to \mathcal O^{\oplus d}(-1) \to \mathcal O^{\oplus c} \to G_2^\vee(-1)\to 0.
$$
As before, we see that the map $\mathcal O^{\oplus c}=H^0(G_2^\vee(-1))\otimes \mathcal O$ with the natural map. As before, the kernel can be shown to be acyclic vector bundle. We just need to argue that the map 
$$
H^0(G_2^\vee(-1))\otimes \mathcal O\to G_2^\vee(-1)
$$
is surjective. This is immediately clear from the decomposition of $G_2$ into invertible sheaves and the fact that $\mathcal O(\geq 0)$ are globally generated.

{\bf Edit:} Here is a replacement for the spectral sequence argument. The long exact sequence splits into 
$$
0\to \mathcal O(-1)^{\oplus a}\to \mathcal O^{\oplus b}\to B_1 \to 0
$$
$$
0\to B_1\to F\to B_2 \to 0
$$
$$
0\to B_2\to \mathcal O(-1)^{\oplus c}\to \mathcal O^{\oplus d}\to 0
$$
From the long exact sequences in cohomology, and from the knowledge of cohomology of $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal O(-1)$, we conclude from the first and third short exact sequences that
$$
H^0(B_1)=\mathbb k^{b},~H^1(B_1)=0,~H^0(B_2)=0,~H^1(B_2)=\mathbb k^d.
$$
If we now apply this knowledge to $0\to B_1\to F\to B_2\to 0$, we see
that $\mathbb k^b=H^0(F)$ and $\mathbb k^d=H^1(F)$. Moreover, it is clear from this argument that the map $H^0(\mathcal O^{\oplus b})\to H^0(F)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I apologize if I'm being silly, but does one really need to think about hypercohomology to answer uniqueness? Namely, won't this extension sit in $\text{Ext}^3(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^{\oplus{d}},\mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus a})$ which is $H^3(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(-1))^{\oplus ad}=0$?

Comment: PS, that's a nice argument! Do you think that the reliance on Grothendieck's theorem is necessary? Do you think that similar questions would be much, much harder on $\mathbb{P}^2$? I would assume so.

Comment: First of all, hypercohomology arguments could be completely removed by just looking at a bunch of short exact sequences. All I want to really argue is that $b=h^0(F)$ with the natural map. I don't see how your $\rm Ext$ argument would work though.

Comment: I certainly think that Grothendieck theorem is crucial here. One could perhaps get something similar on $\mathbb P^n$ from BGG correspondence, but I am not sure of that.

Comment: I was using the fact that any two extensions must have a chain map between them since the ext group is zero, and then was going to say that this chain map must be an isomorphism. I realize now though that making this rigorous would basically reduce to what you said.

Comment: Another comment: existence would certainly be easy just by looking separately at torsion and $\mathcal O(\geq 0)$ that would be resolved from the left, and then $\mathcal O(<0)$ that's resolved from the right.

Comment: @Lev Borisov I am not very good with spectral sequences. Could you please give some additional explanations how to get the numbers $b,d$?

Comment: Also it seems that there is no need to say something about naturality of the map $H^0(F)\otimes\mathcal{O}\to F$. It is just enough to twist the exact sequence by $(-1)$ and then using your argument with the spectral sequence we obtain that $a$ and $c$ express via dimensions of cohomologies of $F(-1)$.

Comment: @guest31 I added some notes to the answer.

Comment: @Lev Borisov  Thank you. Actually that splitting argument is something I could do myself. I asked rather for the explanation of the spectral sequence argument. Anyway, your answer is brilliant, thank you very much for that.

Comment: There is a spectral sequence that starts with $\oplus_{ij}H^i(F_j)$ where $F_j$ is the sheaf at the $j$-th spot and converges to the hypercohomology of the complex. Since the complex is exact, it converges to zero.  The only possible places for the nonzero $H^i(F_j)$ are the cohomology of $F$ and the zeroeth cohomology of copies of $\mathcal O$. By looking at what it takes for spectral sequence to converge to zero, you see claim. It is conceptually equivalent to what one gets from the short exact sequences.